# What is Type in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have come across the `Type` keyword at many places in the documentation. For example [as seen here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentRef-class.html#!#componentType-anchor) `ComponentRef` has the `componentType`  property. It is said to be of type `Type<any>`. On further searching I find [this entry](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Type-decorator.html) about it on the docs. It says: *Invoke as ES7 decorator*.

Also on looking [up the source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/core/src/type.ts#L19-L19) on github , I find these comments :

```
/**
 * @whatItDoes Represents a type that a Component or other object is instances of.
 *
 * @description
 *
 * An example of a `Type` is `MyCustomComponent` class, which in JavaScript is be represented by
 * the `MyCustomComponent` constructor function.
```

However I am still not clear as to what `Type` does. Am I missing something basic ??

Comment: It looks like when the docs were generated, some things got mixed around.  The "Invoke as ES7 decorator" apparently came from the [TypeDecorator](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/core/src/util/decorators.ts#L66) interface.  It kinda makes sense that it was caused by that, the docs were associated with a generic function of type `Type<T>` that returns a `T`, which it satisfies.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Judging by the definition:

```
export const Type = Function;

export interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

`Type` is just a function.  `Type<T>` is just some function/type when constructed (using any combination of arguments), creates a `T`.  So in other words, a "type" definition.  Remember, "types" in javascript (in the OO sense) are represented using functions.  And that equates to classes, interfaces and the like in typescript.

Given that, the following should hold:

```
class Foo {
    s: string;
}
class Bar {
    s: number;
}
class Biz {
    ss: string;
}
class Baz {
    s: string;
    t: number;
}

let x: Type<{ s: string }>; // x is a type that returns an object
                            // with an s property of type string

x = Foo; // ok
x = Bar; // error, s is not a string
x = Biz; // error, doesn't contain s property
x = Baz; // ok
x = { s: "foo" }; // haha nice try
```

Comment: Is this should work for class methods? I have this: let y: Type<{ dump: (times: number) => void }>; and then a class with a member function dump but with return type as number. It seems that TS is not catching that case.

Comment: I think in that case, it's ok because the type is declaring that the `dump()` function returns `void`. Another way to put that is that the function's return value can be ignored. Your actual implementation of `dump()` returns something but we don't necessarily have to consume it. It's probably explained somewhere in the documentation but it looks like it has return type covariance.