# Define typeof abstract class in typescript

Tags: angular, class, typescript, types, abstract-class

How do I make `typeof BaseListComponent` below assignable?

The code below throws the following error:

> Type '`({ title: string; component: typeof QuestionsListComponent;
>   } | { title: string; component: ...'` is not assignable to type `'{
>   title: string; component: typeof BaseListComponent; }[]'`.

**Excerpt:**

```
abstract class BaseListComponent {
  protected title
}

class WeatherListComponent extends BaseListComponent {}

class QuestionsListComponent extends BaseListComponent {}

let containerItems: Array<{title: string, component: typeof BaseListComponent}>;
containerItems = [
  {title:'TypeScript', component: QuestionsListComponent},
  {title:'Angular2', component: QuestionsListComponent},
  {title:'Weather', component: WeatherListComponent}
]
```

P.S this is a simplified excerpt from an angular application and so there is logic behind this madness.

Comment: `BaseListContainerComponent` is not the same as `BaseListComponent`  in your example. Your example works fine for me in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the names but forgot to do so as well in the error message. This is really strange that it doesn't work in an angular environment but it does in the playground...

Comment: In your error message you are trying to assign an 'OR' type (`{} |
 {}`) to an array (`{ ... }[]`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using angular's [`Type`](https://angular.io/api/core/Type) interface was the solution. A better explanation of what `Type` is can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909015/what-is-type-in-angular-2). Steps to solve:

1. Import `Type` like so: `import { Type } from "@angular/core";`
2. Replace `typeof BaseListComponent` with `Type<BaseListComponent>`

---

For people coming here who are not using angular, [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5843) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but isnt `component: typeof BaseListComponent` declaring `component` to be of type `Type`

shouldn't it just be `component: BaseListComponent`

Comment: Thanks for your answer: It results in an error:  `Type '({ title: string; component: typeof QuestionsContainerComponent; } | { title: string; component: ...' is not assignable to type '{ title: string; component: BaseListContainerComponent; }[]'.`