# How to inference class type that implements an interface

Tags: typescript

Given an interface:

```
interface IAnInterface {

}
```

How to reference and point to a class type that implements that interface?

Meaning, given a class:

```
class AClassThatImplmentsAnInterface implements IAnInterface {

}
```

How to reference the type that is a class type? If it was just classes we could use `typeof`:

```
typeof AClassThatImplementsAnInterface
```

but at the interface level, which point to all the classes that implements the interface:

```
typeof IAnInterface
```

gives the error:

```
'IAnInterface' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. (2693)
```

I want to do something like:

```
type IClassTypeMapping = {
 [names in SomeLiteralStringUnion]: Class<IAnInterface>
}
```

Of course `Class` doesn't exist in TypeScript. How to reference the equivalent of `Class<IAnInterface>`? Is it even possible in TypeScript?

Comment: To my knowledge the compiler doesn't keep track of what exactly implements which interface. It'd be quite a heavy data to maintain only for the compilation phase. Moreover, it will be inaccurate in many cases or *too* accurate and thus make compilation even heavier. The problem is that TS uses structural equality to check if something "matches" an interface. So, so you could have `interface A { name: string)` and `class B { name = "Fred" }`. The class doesn't *explicitly* implement the interface, but it's assignable to it.

Comment: Thank you for this development! In mean time! What i was searching is to setup the interface as a class type and not instance! So when you have a class that implements! What get inferred is the interface! Work well in a polymorphic way! The accepted answer show how to do this! Thank you again!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to map to the class itself, not to an instance of the class.  So basically something with is constructable.  I think this type should work for you:

```
type Class<I, Args extends any[] = any[]> = new(...args: Args) => I;
```

We are declaring that `Class<IAnInterface>` can be called with the `new` keyword and some arguments, and will return an `IAnInterface` object (the class instance).

The second argument `Args` allows you to define what the constructor arguments are.  If there are no arguments it would be an empty array.

```
declare const MyClass: Class<IAnInterface, []>;

const instance: IAnInterface = new MyClass();
```

```
declare const OtherClass: Class<IAnInterface, [number, string]>;

const otherInstance: IAnInterface = new OtherClass(0, "");
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/yNaAyN)

Comment: Thank you for this strong answer! And too for the playground!

Answer (score 0):

**(For Angular only)**

Angular has a build in class: [Type](https://angular.io/api/core/Type).

You can read more in the [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909015/what-is-type-in-angular-2).