# How to type a class which produces instances with a specific interface

Tags: typescript

I would like to create class instances out of a list of classes. The only requirement is that those instances have the `IG` interface. Like this:

```
interface IG {
   doMagic: () => void;
}

class ACls implements IG {
    doMagic() { ... }
}

class BCls implements IG {
    doMagic() { ... }
}

const cls = [ACls, BCls]
cls.forEach(Item => (new Item()).doMagic());
```

My question is, how can I enfore this requirement, how should I type  the variable `cls`. For example

```
const cls: IG[] = [ACls, BCls]
```

doesn't work. because I store class references not instances. Any suggestions?

Comment: Based on usage, _"array of things that can be `new`ed up into an `IG`"_: `{ new(): IG }[]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inference class type that implements an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64750214/how-to-inference-class-type-that-implements-an-interface)

Comment: There is one problem with this solution, which is that I don't know anything about the constructor of these classes. I noticed that if there are constructor arguments, the typescript throws an error. I think that the `new()` forces it to have 0 arguments ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoE1kG8CwAoZZAEwHtgwAKASgC5kA3MogbnwF998EAbOAZz5ps+QghIg+YKAFcEYElApwANMgBGVbBwLIAtnADmwBNS0jiZSpqzbCMEiVNZkUCGGlQQyeNz4Rt2lziksjcwJJ0ziAQAO7UdBjIbADaALrIALzIyaiprHhAA))

Comment: I think I found it: `new(...x: any)` If I use `unknown` I get a typing error ([demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoE1kG8CwAoZZAEwHtgwAKASgC5kA3MogbnwF998EAbOAZz5ps+QghIg+YKAFcEYElApw6IaQFsARtAA0yDXQ0kS3CHBBVsHAsjVwA5sATVLI4mUoWsVwjCPOsyFAQYNJQIMjw3HwQVlZc4pLI3MCSdAEgEADuFAB0eQAedNIgANYgJJkgANoAurRomGy1yAC8yFWoNax4QA)). Is there another way to do this without the `any`?

Comment: Well if you're going to `cls.forEach(Item => (new Item()).doMagic())` then each `Item` indeed needs to have a no-args constructor. If there are any args (and you can't be more specific) you need `any` rather than `unknown` because _every_ constructor is going to be called with them. This is why it's generally easier to make arrays of the _instances_, so each can be constructed as appropriate _then_ put in the array.

Comment: True, in my code example I create the instances :) My mistake. Thanks a lot for the support!!